# Get number of dt with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-lists

```
<dl>
<dt>1</dt>
<dd></dd>
<dt>2</dt>
<dd></dd>
<dt>3</dt>
<dd></dd>
<dt>4</dt>
<dd></dd>
<dt>5</dt>
<dd></dd>
</dl>
```

How do I get index of dt element, when user clicks on it? Fifth dt should give 4, first 0.

```
$('dt').click(function(){
var index = 'how to?';
alert('current dt index is ' + index);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do:

```
$('dt').click(function(){
   var index = $(this).prevAll('dt').length;
   alert('current dt index is ' + index);
});
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/erUPs/

EDIT - If you need to just add a class to the next dd you could do:

```
$('dt').click(function(){
    $(this).next('dd').addClass('myclass')

});
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/erUPs/2/

Comment: How do I add class to dd, which goes after current dt?

Comment: If it's just a normal class, you don't need to claclulate the index i think (i edited my answer to do that) http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/erUPs/2/

Answer (score 2):

```
$('dt').bind('click', function () {
    var index = $(this).parent().children('dt').index(this);
});
```

See the [`children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children) method, which accepts a selector, and the [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index) method.

**Edit:**

Add a class to the clicked `dt` using the [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass) method:

```
$('dt').bind('click', function () {
    var self = $(this);
    var index = self.parent().children('dt').index(this);

    self.addClass("foo-" + index);
});
```

I've assigned `$(this)` to `self`, to stop `$(this)` being calculated an unnecessary number of times.

Comment: emm, how do I add class to clicked dt?

Comment: Disclaimer: Use @Nicola's answer... it's more efficient than this.